# Bootstrap Carousel multi columns slide 1 at a time

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

The goal: To have multiple `columns (6)` in a `bootstrap carousel` that slides one column at a time, and goes round in a `circle`.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <h3>Bootstrap 3 Multiple Slide Carousel</h3>

</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e477e4/fff&amp;text=2" class="img-responsive"></a>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=3" class="img-responsive"></a>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f4f4f4&amp;text=4" class="img-responsive"></a>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f566f5/333&amp;text=5" class="img-responsive"></a>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f477f4/fff&amp;text=6" class="img-responsive"></a>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=7" class="img-responsive"></a>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/fcfcfc/333&amp;text=8" class="img-responsive"></a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>

    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 4000
});

$('.carousel .item').each(function() {
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        next = next.next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }

        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.carousel-inner .active.left {
    left: -16.6%;
}

.carousel-inner .next {
    left: 16.6%;
}

.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
    background-image: none;
}
```

I have it set up on this [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/JohnHalsey/abmtmjyz/) ( blatant copy from this [**bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/123662#) -  which does work!)

The problem with mine is that it scrolls all 6 columns at once, however on the next loop, it is the correct slide at the start.

I can't see what I'm doing differently, and been staring at it for ages.

Any advice welcome..... PLEASE!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked this out.  I wouldn't have got it without KAD's answer but changing the version number wasn't really an option for me.

I'm using less files and brought bootstrap in via bower, and it brought in all the separate components into their different files, then they all get added into the one "bootstrap.less" file using @import.

I found the carousel.less file, and found the .carousel-inner class and copied that whole block out into my own .less file so I could override the components.

So this is my new modified class, where the percentages say 16.6%, they were all 100% before.

```
.carousel-inner {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;

    > .item {
      display: none;
      position: relative;
      .transition(.6s ease-in-out left);

      // Account for jankitude on images
      > img,
      > a > img {
        &:extend(.img-responsive);
        line-height: 1;
      }

      // WebKit CSS3 transforms for supported devices
      @media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
          .transition-transform(~'0.6s ease-in-out');
          .backface-visibility(~'hidden');
          .perspective(1000px);

          &.next,
          &.active.right {
            .translate3d(16.6%, 0, 0);
            left: 0;
          }
          &.prev,
          &.active.left {
            .translate3d(-16.6%, 0, 0);
            left: 0;
          }
          &.next.left,
          &.prev.right,
          &.active {
            .translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            left: 0;
          }
      }
    }

    .active,
    .next,
    .prev {
        display: block;

    }
    .active {
        left: 0;
    }

    .next,
    .prev {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .next {
      left: 16.6%;
    }
    .prev {
      left: -16.6%;
    }
    .next.left,
    .prev.right {
      left: 0;
    }

    .active.left {
      left: -16.6%;
    }
    .active.right {
      left: 16.6%;
    }

  }
```

I think the bit that really did it was in the transform-3d section, once I changed that it worked as desired.

This of course, will only work now for carousels with 6 columns, which for me is correct.  So to make sure this style is only applied on this particular carousel, i wrapped the whole thing in the id of the slider, so it will only affect this one.

Hopefully this will be helpful to someone else too.

Comment: Will check it out, seems reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is a difference in the way carousal is handled between bootstrap `CSS` versions, you are using bootstrap v3.3.5 while the example on bootply has bootstrap v3.0.2.

I couldn't really put my hands on the exact difference between the two files but here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abmtmjyz/4/).

Comment: Thanks for this @KAD, so did you just change the external resources to an older version?

Comment: Yes exactly, the same version as bootply

Comment: OK.  But I'm not really sure that helps me.  I'm using a later version in my project and to change version now might be a bit of a nightmare.  I working with .less files and have separate files for all the different components, including carousel, so I'll have a look in there to see if there is anything obvious.

Comment: I think you need to get deeper in the carousal implementation both js and css in order to put your hands on the difference